# Arraylist TextView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview

I created a TextView with an ArrayList, but the output is not showing any text, what am I doing wrong? The xml has all the different views defined in it, with the imageview and multiple textviews, but I cant seem to get it to display any text.

TextItem.java:

```
public class TextItem {
    private int imageId;
    private String description;
    private String description_real;
    private String openingtimes;
    private String openingtimes_real;
    private String prices;
    private String prices_real;

    public TextItem(int imageId, 
            String description, 
            String description_real, 
            String openingtimes, 
            String openingtimes_real, 
            String prices, 
            String prices_real) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.description = description;
        this.description_real = description_real;
        this.openingtimes = openingtimes;
        this.openingtimes_real = openingtimes_real;
        this.prices = prices;
        this.prices_real= prices_real;

    }
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getdescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getdescription_real() {
        return description_real;
    }
    public void setdescription_real(String description_real) {
        this.description_real = description_real;
    }
    public String getopeningtimes(){
        return openingtimes;
    }
    public void setopeningtimes(String openingtimes) {
        this.openingtimes = openingtimes;
    }
    public String getopeningtimes_real(){
        return openingtimes_real;
    }
    public void setopeningtimes_real(String openingtimes_real) {
        this.openingtimes_real = openingtimes_real;
    }
    public String prices(){
        return prices;
    }
    public void setprices(String prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }
    public String getprices_real(){
        return prices_real;
    }
    public void setprices_real(String prices_real) {
        this.prices_real = prices_real;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description + "\n" + description_real + "/n" + "/n" +
                openingtimes + "\n" + openingtimes_real + "/n" + "/n" +
                prices + "\n" + prices_real + "/n" + "/n" ;
    }}
```

Air.java:

```
public class Air extends Activity {

public static final String[] description = new String[] {"Lorem"};

public static final String[] description_real = new String[] {"Lorem"};

public static final String[] openingtimes = new String[] { "Lorem"};

public static final String[] openingtimes_real = new String[] {"Lorem"};

public static final String[] prices = new String[] { "Lorem"};

public static final String[] prices_real = new String[] {"Lorem"};

public static final Integer[] images = { 
        R.drawable.hotel };

    ImageView ImageView;
    TextView TextView;
    List<TextItem> TextItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.textview_item);

        TextItems = new ArrayList<TextItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < description.length ; i++) {
            TextItem item = new TextItem(images[i], 
                    description[i], 
                    description_real[i], 
                    openingtimes[i], 
                    openingtimes_real[i],
                    prices[i],
                    prices_real[i]);
            TextItems.add(item);

    ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_real);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openingtimes);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openingtimes_real);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prices);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prices_real);

        }   
    }
}
```

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_real"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/openingtimes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_real"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/openingtimes_real"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/openingtimes"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/openingtimes_real"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prices_real"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/prices"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would u show me ur xml

Comment: If you are trying to display text in textviews  then where have you set the text to textviews?

Comment: "I created a TextView with an ArrayList" ? where ?

Comment: Added the XML to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textView.setText("SomeText")` is missing

you should do this

```
yourTextView.setText(textItem.getDescription)
```

also you are assigning many values to the same textview inside a loop, this is wrong, u gonna have one `textItems` displayed

#### code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StackActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String[] description = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final String[] description_real = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final String[] openingtimes = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final String[] openingtimes_real = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final String[] prices = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final String[] prices_real = new String[] { "Lorem" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    android.widget.ImageView ImageView;
    android.widget.TextView TextView;
    List<TextItem> TextItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextItems = new ArrayList<TextItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
            TextItem item = new TextItem(images[i], description[i],
                    description_real[i], openingtimes[i], openingtimes_real[i],
                    prices[i], prices_real[i]);
            TextItems.add(item);

            ImageView = (android.widget.ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
            ImageView.setImageResource(TextItems.get(i).getImageId());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).getdescription());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_real);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).getdescription());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.openingtimes);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).getopeningtimes());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.openingtimes_real);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).getopeningtimes_real());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.prices);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).prices());
            TextView = (android.widget.TextView) findViewById(R.id.prices_real);
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(i).getprices_real());
            TextView.setText(TextItems.get(0).getdescription());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Murn for another times, please don't put your widgets into a loop

Comment: @Frencesco Totti Would I accept what? this works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you very much!